# What is the radix of the number if the solution to quadratic equation $x^2-10x+31=0$ is $x = 5$ and $x = 8$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Question:

> What is the radix of the number if the solution to quadratic equation $x^2-10x+31=0$ is $x = 5$ and $x = 8$?

I'm not exactly sure how I'd go about solving this equation. Is it trial and error from base conversions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $b$ be the desired radix; I’ll subscript the numbers that are written in this base; unsubscripted numbers are in base ten. (Note that one-digit numbers are unambiguous, so I don’t bother to subscript then.)

If $x=5$ is a solution to $x^2-10_bx+31_b=0$, then $5^2-10_b\cdot5+31_b=0$. Now $10_b=b$, and $31_b=3b+1$, so what is $b$? If you’re still stuck, the conclusion is spoiler-protected below.

> $5^2-5b+3b+1=0$, and $b=13$. In base ten, then, the quadratic is $x^2-13x+40=0$, which does indeed factor as $(x-5)(x-8)=0$.

Comment: Why does $10_b = b$?

Comment: @Doug: A number written in base $b$ as $d_nd_{n-1}\dots d_1d_0$, where the $d_k$’s are digits, represents $$d_nb^n+d_{n-1}b^{n-1}+\ldots+d_1b^1+d_0b^0\;.$$ Here $n=1$, $d_1=1$, and $d_0=0$, so $10_b=1\cdot b^1+0\cdot b^0=b$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then my only question is when you do this method you outlined in your example, we're converting a number in base `b` to base what exactly? 10? And if so, could you explain? I guess I'm just confused with where we're converting and why.

Comment: @Doug: Everything in that answer that isn’t explicitly marked as being in base $b$ is in base ten (or, being a single digit, is the same in both bases). The conversion to base ten is made so as to bring $b$ explicitly into the notation, so that we can use the given information to solve for $b$ and thereby answer the question.

Comment: @Doug: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  If you let $b$ be the base, you are given that $25-5b+3b+1=0$ (and$ 64-8b+3b+1=0$ but you only need one)

Comment: Isn't that assuming r is 10 (base 10)? As 5^2 = 5 * 5 = 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5, which would only be 25 in base 10?

Comment: @DougSmith:  all my numbers are base 10.  That is why I have $5b,\  3b,$ and $8b$.  In any base $31_b=3b+1$, as in base $10$, we have $31_{10}=3\cdot 10+1$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\rm\:5,8\,$ roots of $\rm\:x^2 - \color{#C00}{10_b}\,x+31_b\:\Rightarrow\: 5+8 = \color{#C00}{10_b} = b.\,$

Comment: This is the easiest approach

Comment: @Ross: The easiest approach is the one that you see first that works. This is probably the most elegant approach, which isn’t necessarily the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

$$ x^2 -  10x  +  31      =  (x-5)(x-8)    $$
 writing in base 10

$$ x^2 - bx  + (3b+1)  =  x^2 - 8x - 5x + 40 $$

that is

$$ x^2 - bx  + (3b+1)  =  x^2 - 13x + 40 $$
 Now comparing the $x$ variable

$$ b=13 $$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. MathJax formatting is expected; for information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).